# Call to Api Marine Traffic javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making this api call and not getting any results. When I make the call from the browser and search with that imo, I get back the vessel information but not in the call from code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="pr"></div>
     <script>

     getInfoVessel("9146314");


    function httpGetAsync(url, callback) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
                callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }    
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    function getInfoVessel(IMO){
        httpGetAsync('http://services.marinetraffic.com/api/exportvessel/v:5/7[herecomesthekey]/protocol:jsono/imo:9146314', function(response) {
            document.getElementById('pr').innerHTML = response;
        });
    }
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is good `Status Code:200 OK` but there is an error in the response `KEY NOT FOUND`.

Try this code:

```
function httpGetAsync(url, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }
}
function getInfoVessel(IMO){
    httpGetAsync('http://services.marinetraffic.com/api/exportvessel/v:5/7[herecomesthekey]/protocol:jsono/imo:' + IMO, function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        document.getElementById('pr').innerHTML = response;
    });
}

getInfoVessel("9146314");
```